# Ajax.BeginForm - need two forms to get it work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

my question is simple.

This code works fine, like expected. Submitting form causes div update. But if I delete the first (empty) form, it won't work anymore. It's needed to be there to work well. Why? It's really annoying for me. Because I can't solve it.

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { })) { }%>

<% using(Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateForm", new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId="textEntered"})) { %>
 <%= Html.TextBox("textBox1")%>  
 <input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br />
 <span id="textEntered">Nothing Entered</span>
<% } %>
```

Hope you will help me. Cheers

EDIT: added full code

view:

```
<head runat="server">
<title>Index</title>
  <script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form runat="server" id="form1">

 <p>
  Page Rendered: <%= DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() %>
 </p>
 <span id="status">No Status</span>
 <br />   
 <%= Ajax.ActionLink("Update Status", "GetStatus", new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId="status" }) %>
 <br /><br />

 <% using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { })) { }%>

 <% using(Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateForm", new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId="textEntered"})){ %>
  <%= Html.TextBox("textBox1")%>  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br />
  <span id="textEntered">Nothing Entered</span>
 <% } %>

</form>
</body>
```

controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

public ActionResult Index()
{
 return View();
}

public string GetStatus()
{
 return "Status OK at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}

public string UpdateForm(string textBox1)
{
 if (textBox1 != "")
 {
    return "You entered: \"" + textBox1.ToString() + "\" at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
 }
 return String.Empty;
 }
}
```

but trust me, the code should work fine, it's made by tutorial.

EDIT2: okey, now it works according to comments. But, if there can't be form in another form, why it works with 3 forms?:) there is one "main" form, and my ajax form. doesn't work. if in "main" form are two ajax forms, it works. Huh?

Comment: why does the post delete "Hi there"? o.O

Comment: Can you show the full version of code in View and Controller?

Comment: ofc, will edit Q in few seconds

Comment: @Egor4eg the code works fine in this form, but if I delete empty Ajax form, it won't work anymore. you can copy/paste it and try.

Comment: Try to remove <form runat="server" id="form1"> and </form> from your code. Nested forms are not allowed in HTML

Comment: wow, it really works, thank you very much! But one question, why does it work, if there are 3 forms?:D btw, make an answer that I can mark as answer:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `<form runat="server" id="form1">` and `</form>` from your code. Nested forms are not allowed in HTML.

I could not reproduce the same issue locally, so in order to investigate why exactly that happens, look at HTML source, debug your HTTP traffic with Fiddler, try that in different browsers etc. 
I suspect that the browser in your case might recognise the second form as a closing tag for the first one, and that's why the third form worked. You can see that if you explore DOM elements tree created by your browser.